# Regex to match all non http links, but not mailto

Tags: regex

How can I alter this regex to not match mailto links?

```
(href|src)\=\"([^(http)])(\/)?
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/BRyZjA1G-iYa26L4)

Should match

```
<a href="myurl">
```

Should not match

```
<a href="http://myurl">
<a href="mailto://myurl">
```

Comment: http://www.regexguru.com/2008/11/detecting-urls-in-a-block-of-text/ may be help you

Comment: can u give an example of what should match and what not

Comment: +1 for directing me to Debuggex. This tool is great!

Answer (score 3):

Just in case someone else comes across this question, I changed it like this

```
(href|src)\=\"(?!http|mailto)(\/)?
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/biMCG-lbQFHKl-pz)

Answer (score 0):

Use a negative lookahead to dismiss urls with mailto

http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: But how does that apply to the regex above?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, try using Negative-lookahead.

This could give you a head-start:

```
(href|src)\=\"(?!(http|mailto))(\/)?
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following one its working :

```
((mailto\:|(news|(ht|f)tp(s?))\://){1}\S+)
```

Here you can test it : http://regexlib.com/RETester.aspx?regexp_id=37